# In JavaScript, does it make a difference if I call a function with parentheses?

Tags: javascript

I noticed a difference when calling a function with empty parentheses, or without any parentheses at all. However, I am not passing any arguments to the function so I wondered, what would be the difference between:

```
window.onload = initAll();
```

and

```
window.onload = initAll;
```

Please explain the principle behind it.

Comment: The `()` characters are called "parentheses". "Brackets" refers to `[]`. I edited your post to conform.

Comment: @JS Bangs - Only in US English; not elsewhere. Although programmers tend to call them "parentheses" to avoid confusion, in UK English the rounded ones are known simply as brackets. The square ones are known as "square brackets". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket

Comment: in programming the `()` are definitely __NOT__ brackets, never had been regardless of locale of the programmer. And for completeness `[]` are brackets and `{}` are braces.

Comment: @fuzzy lollipop - I was just going on the common language I hear developers at all levels use every day and have done for years. If you say "brackets" in the UK, everyone, programmers alike, will think of parenthesis, not square brackets. If you mean "[]", you would have to say square brackets. That's just the way it is.

Comment: on a serious note, the official UNICODE name is Parenthesis.

0028 `(` LEFT PARENTHESIS = opening parenthesis (1.0) and 0029 `)` RIGHT PARENTHESIS = closing parenthesis (1.0) -- http://unicode.org/charts/charindex.html#P

and what Dictionary.com has to say about it -- http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/PARENTHESIS "Either  or  both  of  the  upright  curved  lines,  ( ) ..."

Comment: So this isn't just an "US English" thing, it is an International standard definition because UNICODE is an International Standard.

Comment: @fuzzy - Where do you get your facts from, seriously? [`{}`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket) are called squirrelly brackets.

Comment: It is amazing this post got 12+ up votes? initAll() is the result of the function intAll is the function itself. That is basic JavaScript.

Comment: @fuzzy lollipop - Unicode is an international standard on encoding characters as bytes, not on naming. The authors of the unicode document are not claiming the given name for a character is an international standard. It is the code vs. the character they are defining. But, you might like to note that they also refer to [ and ] as square brackets - (not just "brackets"), and that they refer to all of [, { and ( as bracketing characters. You should strive to understand the nuances in the way different places use the same words. Very important if you are part of an international team.

Comment: brackets might be a class of surrounding characters like your link to the wikipedia article states that () are still parenthesis, proving my point for me. And my point __exactly__ is semantics are important, in programming they are called paranethesis, to semantically disambiguate them from the other "brackets". I guess you refer to & as a symbol and not an ampersand as well? Same line of reasoning. All IDE's preferences refer to `()` as parenthsis and `[]` as brackets and `{}` as braces. And the offical UNICODE name is parenthsis for those characters and all the other "bracket" like curved.

Comment: So to my point you should refer to them by the un-ambiguous names, Internationally just like UNICODE does and every IDE does. http://www.vertigrated.com/images/prefs.png

Comment: Agreed - it is better to refer to () as parenthesis to avoid ambiguity - I said that programmers tend to in my 1st comment. However, there is nothing more ambiguous than expecting people to use language in a way that is at odds with what they are used to. If you mean "[]" in the UK you'll have to say square brackets. And if someone says "brackets", everyone will assume round ones, not square ones. It matters, for purposes of clarity, not one jot what any standard says if people don't follow it. I'm sure if you look through all the Unicode standard you'll spot your own examples of this too.

Comment: You have to understand that most languages and standards are biased heavily towards US English. The moment you leave US English as the primary language, things get a lot more ambiguous. Things that are dead set standards in US English can go against the way the rest the the English speaking world have been taught, not to mention other languages. If you want to be clear and unambiguous, then use language that won't be misunderstood by anyone. Parenthesis - fair enough. Brackets instead of square brackets, forget it.

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between a function call and function reference?](/q/15886272/4642212).

Answer (score 166, accepted):

> ```
> window.onload = initAll();
> ```

This **executes** `initAll()` **straight away** and assigns the **function's return value** to `window.onload`. This is usually **not** what you want. `initAll()` would have to return a function for this to make sense.

> ```
> window.onload = initAll;
> ```

this assigns the **actual function** to `window.onload` - this is possible because in JavaScript, as @Felix says, functions are first class objects - without executing it. `initAll` will be executed by the load event.

You may also see something like this:

```
window.onload = () => initAll();
```

This will create a new function that, **when called**, will call `initAll` **immediately**. Parentheses are necessary here for that "*call `initAll` immediately*" part to work. But, because it's wrapped in a function, nothing will execute until that outer function itself is called, and you assign the reference of that outer function to `window.onload`, so `initAll` will also be executed on the load event.

Comment: Important to mention here is that functions are first class objects in JavaScript.

Answer (score 140):

What Pekka says is correct, but I want to elaborate a little with an example that will help explain to someone who doesn't fully understand function pointers or delegates.

I won't use `window.onload` because that's a bit contrived to demonstrate. I'll use a simple multiply function to demo instead:

```
function Multiply(operator, operand) {
    return operator * operand;
}
```

This could equally be written:

```
Multiply = function(operator, operand) {
    return operator * operand;
}
```

While in the first example, the implication may not be obvious, the second example shows more clearly that we're assigning a function which has 2 parameters to a variable called `Multiply`, and this concept of functions as assignments is common throughout JavaScript. This is a small demonstration of the fact that functions are *"first class citizens"*, that is, they can be passed around exactly as if we were passing around values.

So now to the difference of assignment:

```
var operator = 3;
var operand = 4;
var ret = Multiply(operator, operand);
```

At the point of defining the ret variable, `Multiply` is executed and the return value is assigned - `ret` becomes equal to 12.

Let's try that again a different way:

```
var operator = 3;
var operand = 4;
var ret = Multiply;
```

Now, at the point of defining `ret`, `ret` becomes your `Multiply` function as opposed to being the result obtained from your `Multiply` function. Calls to `ret()` will cause your `Multiply` function to be executed, and you can call it exactly as if you'd called `Multiply(operator, operand)`:

```
var out = ret(3, 4);
```

is the same as

```
var out = Multiply(3, 4);
```

You have effectively said that you are going to use `ret` as a delegate for `Multiply()`. When calling `ret`, we're really referring to the `Multiply` function.

Back to your `window.onload`. Think of this as:

```
window.onload = function() {
    //Doing what all good window.onload functions should do...
}

initAll = function() {
    return 12;
}
```

So as you can see, `window.onload` is a function just like any other function, there's nothing special about it.  You can assign it a value, assign it a function, null it out if you wish - the point is that there's nothing any more special about `window.onload` than there is about your own function.  The only slightly different thing is that it gets called by the window when it's loaded. [Disclaimer: I've never actually nulled out window functions, so I'm not sure if this will cause negative repercussions.  One would hope they check to see if a function is assigned before calling it i.e. `if (window.onload) window.onload();`].

Now calling `initAll()` what we're saying is:

```
window.onload = initAll();
```

which might as well say:

```
window.onload = 12;
```

But when we say `initAll` without the parentheses, what we're really saying is: I want to replace whatever my window.onload function is, with a new function - i.e. I want to replace it with my `initAll` function, so that any calls to `window.onload` runs my `initAll` code.

So:

```
window.onload = function() {
    //Doing what all good window.onload functions should do...
}
```

is replaced with:

```
window.onload = function() {
    return 12;
}
```

So any call to `window.onload` will execute your `initAll` function instead of whatever `window.onload` was originally.  You have replaced the original function with your new function.

In fact, you *could* equally write:

```
window.onload = function() {
    //Write all your init code right in here instead of having a separate 
    //initAll function.
}
```

Another example that may demonstrate better is this:

```
var d = new Date();
var currentTime = d.getTime();
```

Whatever the time was at the time `d` is defined ends up assigned to `currentTime`.  Great, but that's only useful if we want to find out what time the function containing that code was called - i.e. at page load time.  What if we want the current time any time that `currentTime` is called?

```
var currentTime = function() {
    var d = new Date();
    return d.getTime();
}

var a = currentTime(); //The current time at the point a is defined...
var b = currentTime;   //b is a functional reference to currentTime...
var c = b(); //The current time when variable c is defined
var d = c; //The current time when variable c was defined
```

Notice how we call `b()` in our `c` and `d` assignments exactly as we could call `currentTime()`?

Comment: Hey, what if I want to add a function that takes arguments on an event listener?

Answer (score 17):

Functions in javascript are first-class citizens, and as such, can be assigned to other variables or passed around as arguments.

So, when you do

```
window.onload = initAll;
```

You are setting the `onload` property of the `window` object to reference the `initAll` function itself.

When you do

```
window.onload = initAll();
```

You are setting the `onload` property to hold the *return value* of initAll, since it will execute in place on that line.

Answer (score 13):

I'm 6 years late but I feel this could have been explained a lot simpler than the above answers.

So here is the **TLDR**; or **bird's eye view** when calling functions using and not using `()`'s

Lets take this function for example:

```
function foo(){
return 123;
}
```

---

#### if you log "foo" - **without** `()`

```
console.log(foo); 

---outout------
function foo(){
return 123;
}
```

Using no `()` means to **fetch the function itself**. You would do this if you want it to be passed along as a callback.

---

#### if you log "foo()" - **with** `()`

```
console.log(foo());
-----output-----
 123
```

Using `()` after a function means to execute the function and **return it's value**.

Answer (score 12):

`initAll` is a reference to a function value and the brackets operator appended to the function name RUNS this function object.

So if you do something like

```
a = initAll
```

then `a` will become the same as `initAll` - for example you can do `a()` - but with

```
a = initAll()
```

the variable `a` will get the return value of the executed `initAll` function