# Calling JS functions assigned to variables

Tags: javascript

Some time ago I asked a question about the same issue, @BenAlabaster explained it thoroughly [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246928/in-javascript-does-it-make-a-difference-if-i-call-a-function-with-parentheses/3247044#3247044), I guess I am still missing a piece of logic here.

I tried to call functions that are assigned to variables like I've shown below, in the last function.
Well it didn't work. Assuming it happened because the variable `functionThree` is outside the `addOnload()` function, I tried to move it inside and the browser just crashed.

```
addOnload(functionOne);
addOnload(functionTwo);
addOnload(functionThree);

function addOnload(newFunction){
    oldOnload = window.onload;

    if(typeof oldOnload == "function"){
        window.onload = function(){
            if(oldOnload){
                oldOnload();
            }
                newFunction();    //This is what I missed, and that's what caused the crash. 
        }
    }
    else{
        window.onload = newFunction;
    }
}   

function functionOne(){
    alert("This is the first function on this page!");
}

function functionTwo(){
    alert("This is the second function on this page!");
}

functionThree = function(){
    alert("This is the third function on this page!");
}
```

Comment: Like @Tomalak said below, I moved '
functionThree = function()' inside the 'addOnload' function to declare the variables. And the browser hanged because of a mistake I made.

Comment: Also see [Function expressions vs. Function declarations](http://yura.thinkweb2.com/named-function-expressions/#expr-vs-decl)

Answer (score 3):

This happens because you use `functionThree` before it is defined.

```
function x() { 
  // a function that can be used before its declaring block
}

x = function() {
  // a variable that gets assigned a function object when the execution
  // of the program reaches this point, but not before
}
```

Apart from that, your implementation of `addOnload()` should go something like this:

```
function addOnload(newFunction){
  if (typeof window.onloadFunctions === "undefined") {
    window.onloadFunctions = [];
    window.onloadFunctions.push(window.onload);

    window.onload = function() {
      for(var i=0; i<window.onloadFunctions.length; i++) {
        var f = window.onloadFunctions[i];
        if (typeof f === "function") f();
      }
    }
  }
  window.onloadFunctions.push(newFunction);
}
```

Comment: I just moved the declaration inside and it works.
The browser hand because of a different error I made.

Comment: I will check yours too, but the one I posted works fine + it's short.

Answer (score 3):

There is a slight issue with your addOnloadFunction: it should be:

```
function addOnload(newFunction){
    var oldOnload = window.onload;

    if(typeof oldOnload == "function"){
        window.onload = function(){
            newFunction();
            oldOnload();
        }
    }
    else{
        window.onload = newFunction;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your version is still missing the "var" keyword declaring oldOnload as a local variable