# do I need parenthesis when using a named function as an jquery ajax success callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

if I have a function defined earlier, do I need to include parenthesis when specifying that it should be used for a success callback?

what would be the difference if I did?

as in

```
function fish_food(){//do something}

$.ajax({
    url: '/',
    success: fish_food
});
```

or

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/',
    success: fish_food()
});
```

Comment: Basically no. Why don't you try it and tell us :D

Comment: Related: [When do I use parens and when do I not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969088/when-do-i-use-parenthesis-and-when-do-i-not)

Comment: Haha! 6 answers in 4 mins!  for this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fish_food` on its own (without parens) acts as a reference to the function object. It allows you to pass the reference to the function around to be invoked at some later date.

`fish_food()` (with parens) is a function invocation expression, which causes the function to be executed. The function code is evaluated and run with a value optionally being returned.

With the AJAX code you supplied (and all async JavaScript involving callbacks) you want to use the `fish_food` version (without parens). This passes the AJAX code a reference to your success function, to be executed asynchronously once the AJAX code has completed its round trip to the server and back.

Answer (score 4):

No.

Parentheses will tell the browser that function `fish_food` needs to be executed immediately, and the value has to be returned to a `success` property.

Answer (score 0):

You want the no-parens version. The reason is that the parentheses tell JavaScript to execute the function right away, rather than just reference it by name, so your `success` callback would actually be the results of invoking `fish_food()` whenever you are executing the AJAX call (which is probably going to be an error involving `undefined`).

Answer (score 0):

this will work

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/',
    success: fish_food
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the parenthesis.  Using parens would invoke the function, what it needs is just a name which is equivalent to function pointers in C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

Having the parenthesis causes the function to execute then and there, that is why you need first version else success stores return value of the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/',
    success: fish_food
});
```

is correct.

When you use `success: fish_food()`, it will be executed right away and the return is set to success.