# Custom function not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm passing the click event into my function but doesn't seem to be working?

```
$('body').on("click", youclick(event));

function youclick(e){
    console.log("testing");
    e.stopPropagation();

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does click event handler fire immediately upon page load?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102413/why-does-click-event-handler-fire-immediately-upon-page-load)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Rajaprabhu suggested. When you are using a *callback function(youclick(e))*, the *callback argument(youclick)* is passed as the function name itself without arguments or even the opening or closing braces.

```
It means that a reference of the function is passed in the function call.
```

[**How CallBack Function works?**](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/)

> Because functions are first-class objects in JavaScript, we can treat
>   functions like objects, so we can pass functions around like variables
>   and return them in functions and use them in other functions. When we
>   pass a callback function as an argument to another function, we are
>   only passing the function definition. We are not executing the
>   function in the parameter. We aren’t passing the function with the
>   trailing pair of executing parenthesis () like we do when we are
>   executing a function.
>
> And since the containing function has the callback function in its
>   parameter as a function definition, it can execute the callback
>   anytime. This allows us to execute the callback functions at any point
>   in the containing function.
>
> It is important to note that the callback function is not executed
>   immediately. It is “called back” (hence the name) at some specified
>   point inside the containing function’s body.

```
$('body').on("click", youclick);

function youclick(e){
    console.log("testing");
    e.stopPropagation();

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just pass the `reference` of that `function` itself. And you don't need to pass the `event`, you can receive that through `global scope`,

Try,

```
$('body').on("click", youclick);

function youclick(e){
    console.log("testing");
    e.stopPropagation();

}
```