# Passing a variable to a function bound to a form submission breaks preventDefault and return false

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm trying to execute a function that is bound to a form which stops the browser from submitting the form and checks that form for missing fields, and if there aren't any, it proceeds to submit the form via Ajax

The issue is, the page contains many very similar forms with identical fields, only with unique numbers after the ID for each form element. I want to pass that number to the function that is bound to the relevant form, however when I initialise any variable other than the 'event' variable, the form submits and ignores event.preventDefault(); AND/OR return false;

Here's a simple test:

http://jsfiddle.net/q3mae60g/

Here's the code:

**JS:**

```
$('#contact-form1').submit( submitForm("1") );

function submitForm(formId,event) {

    var contactForm = $(this);
        var forename = '#contact-forename' + formId;
        var surname = '#contact-surname' + formId;
        var email = '#contact-email' + formId;
        var tel = '#contact-tel' + formId;

    if ( !$(forename).val() || !$(surname).val() || !$(email).val() || !$(tel).val() ) {

        $('.form-status').removeClass("current-status");
        $('.contact-incomplete').addClass("current-status");

    } else {

        $('.form-status').removeClass("current-status");
        $('.contact-sending').addClass("current-status");

        $.ajax( {
            url: contactForm.attr( 'action' ) + "?ajax=true",
            type: contactForm.attr( 'method' ),
            data: contactForm.serialize(),
            success: submitFinished
        } );
    }
    return false;
}
```

It seems like the problem lies in the attempt to pass a variable to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.submit()` need a function **reference**. What you are doing is calling a function that return the value `false`. It is like doing :

```
$('#contact-form1').submit( false );
```

Which does nothing.

What you can do is to pass an anonymous function that call your function. Something like that :

```
$('#contact-form1').submit( function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    submitForm.call(this, "1", e);
});
```

Comment: But this works fine:

`$('#contact-form1').submit( submitForm );`

Comment: @DanielvanderSpuy That's because you are passing a reference (as `.submit()` expect). When adding the `()`, you are calling it! That might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102413/why-does-click-event-handler-fire-immediately-upon-page-load

Comment: Okay I think I understand, but nevertheless, your suggestion for the more complex function/call still causes the form to be submitted in the traditional way. I don't understand what is causing the function to break.

Thanks for your help thus far :)

Comment: @DanielvanderSpuy Did you pass the `e` in `.submit(function(**e**`? If you, did you use `e.preventDefault()` in the same function? Any error in the console?

Comment: Yeah I did, and there's no chance to catch any errors as I get directed away from the page by the submission :/

Comment: @DanielvanderSpuy move the `e.preventDefault()` above the function call. If it still submit, post you entire code in a pasteBin (HTML and JS only). If it doesn't submit, you'll be able to see if there is an error in your code.

Comment: Moving the preventDefault in conjunction with your initial suggestion seemed to fix it.

Although the 'formId' variable is being returned as [object Object] rather than 1 when I print it to the console. Any idea why that may be?

Comment: @DanielvanderSpuy That's wierd.... Are you using `submitForm.call()` or `submitForm()`?

Comment: Function call: `submitForm.call(this, "1", e);`
Function itself: `function submitForm(currentThis,formId,e) { ...`

Comment: Okay it works now with `function submitForm(formId,e) {`, so I guess the 'this' was to say what the form is being applied to, as opposed to a variable passed to the form?

Comment: @DanielvanderSpuy excatly, the first parameter in `.call()` will be the `this` in the function!