# window.onbeforeunload fires when entering the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.saveStats = function () {
  $http({
    method: "post",
    url: "save.php",
    data: $scope.info
  }).success(function () {
    console.log($scope.info);
  })
};

window.onbeforeunload = $scope.saveStats();
```

This code is not doing what I expect it to do. It just fires `saveStats()` when loading the page. And when I exit the page, it does not fire `saveStats()`.

I wrote this inside my angular controller.
I'm pretty confused at the result...

Comment: What does `x = foo();` do? Right! So that's exactly what `window.onbeforeunload = $scope.saveStats();` does.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does click event handler fire immediately upon page load?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102413/why-does-click-event-handler-fire-immediately-upon-page-load)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
window.onbeforeunload = $scope.saveStats();
                                        ^^^
```

By adding `()` to the end of `saveStats`, you're executing the function *immediately*. What you want to do is pass a reference to `saveStats` to your `onbeforeunload` like this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = $scope.saveStats;
```

Comment: Depends on whether `saveStats` needs `this` to be `$scope`; if it does, you'll need a `bind`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Good point to highlight, but the code provided doesn't use `this`

Comment: DAMNIT, that was a lame mistake. Thank you for taking the time and clearing it up in such a great way. -- I have to wait a bit before I'm allowed to accept this as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 window.onbeforeunload = $scope.saveStats;
```

You are just trying to pass the function by reference, not executing it, so remove the double brackets that trigger the function.