# ReferenceError when calling function in external script from a script tag

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I feel like there is something very little I'm doing wrong, but I can't find it. I can't figure out how to call an externally-defined function from within a script tag, it keeps giving me `ReferenceError`'s.

I've reduced my code to the most minimal, so here's what I've got. This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <button id="mrbutton" type="button">Mr Button</button>
  <div id="barChart"></div>
  <script src="d3/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="d3/charts/bar.js"></script>
  <script>
    chartParams = {};
    document.getElementById('mrbutton').addEventListener('click', () => {createBarChart(chartParams)});
  </script>
</head>
</html>
```

`d3/d3.min.js` is D3 version 3. Here's what I have in `d3/charts/bar.js`:

```
'use strict';

const createBarChart = params => {
  console.log('hello there!');
};

console.log('script loaded!');
```

But when I load up the page, the Javascript console spits out:

```
script loaded!
Uncaught ReferenceError: createBarChart is not defined
```

If I move the code in `d3/charts/bar.js` into the `<script>` tag in the HTML, it works fine, but I want to reuse the code so I want it external. What am I doing wrong? Why can't I call `createBarChart`?

**Update:** Using Babel to compile down to Ecmascript2015 doesn't change anything, still the same `ReferenceError`. Also changed the event listener to an arrow function.

**Update:** I removed the D3 code and am just calling a console.log(), but still no luck.

Comment: `.addEventListener('click', createBarChart(chartParams))` is also wrong. You are calling the method and assigning whatever it returns to the click event, not calling the method on click

Comment: Are you sure? I don't think that's how `.addEventListener()` works. The second argument according to MDN is "The object which receives a notification (an object that implements the Event interface) when an event of the specified type occurs."

Comment: lol, yes that is HOW it works. You would need to define it as `.addEventListener('click', () => createBarChart(chartParams))`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102413/why-does-click-event-handler-fire-immediately-upon-page-load

Comment: Alright sure, now it's an arrow function. That's not my problem though.

Comment: but that is how your function was being called before you even clicked the button....

Comment: When you inspect the script, what do you see?

Comment: Do you mean with dev tools? Under sources, I see my script as expected. I don't know how to do any inspecting other than that.

Comment: Tested code and it works so unless your d3/charts/bar.js is actually different than what you posted, I have no clue.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. Not sure if this will help anyone else (hopefully it can), but I **just restarted my computer**. That's all; no code changes whatsoever. My original code works fine now (even the original `.addEventListener()`).

It wasn't a browser caching issue, since I tried several browsers in private mode, and I still really don't know what the problem is. If anyone has any idea what it was, please do comment, I'm still puzzled despite being able to move on.

Comment: Things like this are why I have trust issues. :'( Glad you figured it out!