# Delegation event onchange triggers immediately on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange, jquery-events, delegation

**Scenario 1:**

```
$(function () {
    $('#disp_body').on('change', '#image', showMyImage(this));
});
```

If I call the function `showMyImage` directly it calls on page load itself.

**Scenario 2:**

But if I call through closure function. The event properly listened and handled. So it's working properly.

```
$(function () {
    $('#disp_body').on('change', '#image', function() {
        showMyImage(this);
    });
});
```

I like to know really why the scenario 1 is not working but scenario 2.

Comment: There are two levels of execution here.  You should debug the execution order to understand why this is happening otherwise you'll be running into this frequently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7102440/7316502

In case 1, you are invoking a function, and passing its return value to the change listener as a callback. This results in the premature execution of `showMyImage`.

In case two, you are passing a function to be used as a callback, but you are not calling it directly. This allows the change listener to call it and invoke `showMyImage` on the change event as you desire.