# Using a function on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a custom function called `thisAnimate` I'd like to call when an element is clicked. The problem is it works if I put the function inside an empty function using the jQuery `on`, but not if I use the function directly.

Why can't I use the function directly in the `on` function?

THIS CODE WILL WORK

```
var element = $(this);

element.on( 'click', function() {
    thisAnimate(element);
});
```

THIS CODE WILL NOT WORK ???

```
var element = $(this);

element.on( 'click', thisAnimate(element));
```

Comment: because you are executing it and assigning what it returns to the click listener. There is also no reason why you need to pass element to that method.

Comment: Because you invoke the function instead of passing reference to that function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does click event handler fire immediately upon page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102413/why-does-click-event-handler-fire-immediately-upon-page-load)

Comment: `element.on( 'click', thisAnimate(element));` equals `let temp = thisAnimate(element);element.on( 'click', temp);`

Comment: epascarello, why wouldn't I need to pass the element variable to the function? When I'm trying to use `$(this)` in the function it doesn't work.

Comment: `element` exists at a higher scope level.  It will be available in all nested scopes.

Comment: taplar, thats originally what I thought but it isn't working like that. Variables I am declaring in a higher scope don't seem to work in other functions. I'm still learning JS but I am adept at PHP so I have some understanding of how this should work.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gxawynkn/  javascript is not php.  @CoryNickerson

Comment: jsfiddle.net/zo6bo8gL

I try it both with and without using the variable for thisElement in the function. Only works with.

Comment: Because `thisElement` is not at the same or higher scope to `animateThis` in that fiddle.  It is a nested variable in the callback for the each, which is at a lower scope than the `animateThis` function. @CoryNickerson

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zo6bo8gL/15/  But still, you don't have to pass it in.

Answer (score 0):

Because the second parameter of the `on()` function is a function to be executed, not the result of a function execution.

This code:

```
element.on( 'click', function() {
    thisAnimate(element);
});
```

Means, when the button is clicked, execute the anonymous function, which in turn executes the `thisAnimate()` function and passes it the `element` parameter. However, inside the anonymous function, `this` refers to the element that raised the event. So if you want to pass it to the `thisAnimate()` function, you should write:

```
element.on( 'click', function() {
    thisAnimate(this);
});
```

Although in your code, you declared the `element` variable at a higher scope, so it is accessible to the `thisAnimate()` function without having to pass it in a parameter.

Similarly, this code:

```
element.on( 'click', thisAnimate);
```

Means, when the button is clicked, execute the `thisAnimate()` function. It will be automatically passed the standard event parameters (e.g. `event`). Inside the `thisAnimate()` function, `this` refers to the element that raised the event.

But this code:

```
element.on( 'click', thisAnimate(element));
```

Means, when the button is clicked, execute the returned value of the `thisAnimate()` function. This obviously doesn't make any sense unless the `thisAnimate()` function returns a function. For most cases, this is an error. Again, the `element` variable is undefined.

Comment: Appreciate the help. This is what I'm working on. jsfiddle.net/zo6bo8gL/12/

Comment: Taplar gave you the correct way to do it http://jsfiddle.net/zo6bo8gL/15/. Like I said, when you use the event properly `element.on( 'click', thisAnimate)`, you get `this` referring to the element that raised the event, so you don't need to pass it. But when you call `thisAnimate()` directly in your `else` branch, `this` will be the `window` object, so you have call it with a scoped `this` using the `call()` method like `animateThis.call(thisElement)`.

Answer (score -1):

The `on` method can be thought as:

```
element={
    on:function(nameOfEvent, callBackFunction){
        //
    }
};
```

now here '`callBackFunction`' should refer to a function object.
Because that function need to be called when '`nameOfEvent`' will occur.
if `thisAnimate(element)` returns a function object then `element.on( 'click', thisAnimate(element));` would also work. But sadly this statement does not return a function object.