# Onmouseover event is fired when not expected

Tags: javascript, html, onmouseover

I was learning javascript and experimenting with mouse events. In this code I am trying to manipulate the element when I put the mouse over it with the help of an alert box. However the problem is that the alert box is shown even when the mouse is not over the element.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>testing</title>
</head>

<body>
    <a>dasdasd</a>
    <p id="k">as</p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     
     document.getElementById("k").onmouseover=alert('Hello');
     
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: By doing `function()` (with parentheses), you are *executing* the function, not *passing* it. Instead, do `onmouseover = function() { alert('Hello'); }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does click event handler fire immediately upon page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102413/why-does-click-event-handler-fire-immediately-upon-page-load)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property `onmouseover` expect that you assing a function to it, instead you are assigning the evaluation of an expression, in this case: `alert("hello")`. So when the document loads, it evaluate that expression and the alert is shown, then a `null` value is assigned to the `onmouseover` property, that is the reason the alert only shows once.

For your goal, you can use an anonymous function to wrap the alert and assing it to the property. Check the next example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>testing</title>
</head>

<body>
    <a>dasdasd</a>
    <p id="k" style="border: 1px solid red">as</p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     
     document.getElementById("k").onmouseover = function() {alert('Hello')};
     
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out.Really grateful.

Answer (score 2):

try to add `onmouseover="mouseover()"` in `<p>`

```
       function mouseover() {
            alert('Hello');
         }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>testing</title>
</head>

<body>
    <a>dasdasd</a>
    <p id="k" onmouseover="mouseover()">as</p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     function mouseover() {
     alert('Hello');
     }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put it in a function like so.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>testing</title>
</head>

<body>
    <a>dasdasd</a>
    <p id="k">as</p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     
     document.getElementById("k").onmouseover = function(){alert('Hello')};
     
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is, the `()` after the *alert* function causes the function invocation on page load and you see the *alert*. Call the function inside of an anonymous function which will ensure that the function will be called only when the *event (onmouseover)* is fired:

```js
document.getElementById("k").onmouseover = function(){alert('Hello')};
```

```html
<a>dasdasd</a>
<p id="k">as</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this (with JQuery):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").mouseover(function(){
        alert("Hello");
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Move the mouse pointer over this paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This question is not related to jQuery.