# Using keypress or keydown event without an input element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

i'm building a drum machine and i want to be able trigger drum sounds with specific keys on the keyboard. I added event listeners for keypress and keydown events but the sounds are not played when those keys are pressed. The current JavaScript code to do this is below(I also used the function in an input element and it triggered the sound successfully);

```
document.getElementById('drumpad1').addEventListener('keypress', tFunction(event));
function tFunction(event) {
  var key = event.keyCode;     
  var char = String.fromCharCode(key);    
  var charUp = char.toUpperCase()
  if (char === 'q' || charUp === 'Q') {
      document.getElementById("beat").play();
  }
}
```

I also have tried `document.body.addEventListener()` didn't work.
please help

Comment: `.addEventListener('keypress', tFunction(event));` should be `.addEventListener('keypress', tFunction);`.  Give the method a callback, not an invocation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does click event handler fire immediately upon page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102413/why-does-click-event-handler-fire-immediately-upon-page-load)

Comment: Instead of `tFunction(event)` you should use `event => tFunction(event)`.

Comment: @CherryDT Why?  Why make an extra anonymous method that is not needed?

Comment: Because this will then also work with other cases like `event => fn(something, event, somethingElse)`. It will therefore probably be easier to understand and apply by the OP. But actually I didn't mean to correct your comment but the OP's code. Just `tFunction` of course works too in this case.

Comment: "Will work with other cases" isn't relevant.  It's unnecessary for this case, and most cases, unless you have issues with scope changing.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```js
document.getElementById('drumpad1').addEventListener('keypress', tFunction(event));
```

by

```js
document.addEventListener('keypress', tFunction);
```

This will work if the document is in focus.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102413/why-does-click-event-handler-fire-immediately-upon-page-load  This is a known duplicate