# JavaScript - implementing map function with reduce, error when passing function as argument

Tags: javascript, function, functional-programming, reduce

I am trying to implement a map function in javascript using reduce.

```
function newMap(inputArr, fn) {
    return inputArr.reduce((mapItem, elem) => 
        mapItem = (fn(elem)), [])
}

function plusTwo(num) {
    return num + 2;
}

newMap(arr, plusTwo())

console.log(newMap)
```

The error output is: "TypeError: fn is not a function"

So my question is -- what am I doing wrong that the reduce function signature or the function being passed is throwing an error?

P.S. -- still learning javascript, if someone could help edit the title for more clarity, that'd be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: There is already a `map()` function.... ?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Yes, I understand, however I am implementing my own for the purposes of learning.

Comment: `newMap(arr, plusTwo())` <= take the () off of the `plusTwo`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does click event handler fire immediately upon page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102413/why-does-click-event-handler-fire-immediately-upon-page-load)

Comment: @Taplar, great the error went away, but now it returns a function object. I'll keep fooling around, thanks.

Comment: Your reduce logic should be pushing the result to the to the mapItem array, not assigning the single result to it.

Comment: @Taplar correct, I fixed it with the .concat method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `plusTwo` when passing it, but you need to only call `plusTwo` inside the reduce callback. Inside the reduce callback, add the call of `fn(elem)` onto the accumulator array.

```js
function newMap(inputArr, fn) {
    return inputArr.reduce((accum, item) => [...accum, fn(item)], []);
}

function plusTwo(num) {
    return num + 2;
}

const arr = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(newMap(arr, plusTwo));
```

Answer (score 0):

The callback you pass to reduce is expected to return something. Plus what others commented, you want to pass `plusTwo`, not `plusTwo()`, which is a `NaN` (the result of `undefined+2`):

```js
function newMap(inputArr, fn) {
    return inputArr.reduce((accum, item) => {
        accum.push(fn(item));
        return accum;
    }, []);
}

function plusTwo(num) {
    return num + 2;
}

const arr = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(newMap(arr, plusTwo));

console.log("plusTwo:", plusTwo);
console.log("plusTwo():", plusTwo());
```

Answer (score 0):

- `mapItem` is the reference to the resulting array. You need to push the resulting value to it instead of reassigning it in every iteration, ie `mapItem.push(fn(elem))`
- Pass in `plusTwo` as a function instead of invoking it `plusTwo()`, this is why you were getting the `fn is not a function` error
- Print the result of `newMap` instead of `newMap` itself

```js
function newMap(inputArr, fn) {
  return inputArr.reduce((mapItem, elem) => {
      mapItem.push(fn(elem))
      return mapItem;
  }, [])
}

function plusTwo(num) {
    return num + 2;
}

let result = newMap([1,2,3], plusTwo)

console.log(result)
```