# JavaScript Event Listener Inline vs. Explicit

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I am using Tampermonkey for some webpage manipulation and automation. For this, I add an event listener to the window "load" event. When I define the event handler as an explicit function, it works smoothly and as expected, i.e. the function is called whenever the relevant page is loaded.

```
window.addEventListener("load", run());

function run() {
    // do something
}
```

However, when I define the handler inline as follows

```
window.addEventListener("load", function (){
     // do something
});
```

then I need to refresh / reload the page several times before the function gets executed.

What is the explanation to have such very different behaviour? I would have expected no difference whether I define the function "explicitly" as in the first example, or "inline" as in the second one. As I have not noticed this before I don't even know whether this is a Tampermonkey issue or a Javascript one.

Comment: `("load", run());` should actually be `("load", run);` - you want to *use* that callback on *load* triggering, not execute it at will. So this now changes your question completely I guess. Or it solves it.

Comment: The first snippet really doesn't work as expected, instead of executing `run` after the window has been loaded, it calls `run` immediately when the line `window.addEventListener("load", run());` is met.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Why does click event handler fire immediately upon page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7102413) or [What is the difference between a function call and function reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15886272)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.addEventListener("load", run());` does not run the `run` function on `load` but immeditaly and the value returned by `run` is then used as callback (which is likely `undefined`). This is a duplicate to [addEventListener calls the function without me even asking it to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310423/addeventlistener-calls-the-function-without-me-even-asking-it-to)

About the:

> then I need to refresh / reload the page several times before the function gets executed.

You then likely register the event listener to late (at a point when the page was possibly already loaded).

> I don't even know whether this is a Tampermonkey issue or a Javascript one.

It is none of these, it is a false assumption from your side that the site cannot be already loaded at the time you register the load event.

You like want to have something similar to the `ready` function of jQuery which an example implementation without jQuery can be found here [$(document).ready equivalent without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery).

Answer (score 0):

Tl;Dr: pass your function, don't execute it. Let the `"load"` listener handler execute it instead:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", run);
```

---

`run()` **executes** your function, and returns `undefined` by default: *`window.addEventListener("load", undefined); // and executed.`  *

```js
window.addEventListener("load", run()); // run() executes immediately

function run() {
  // do something
}
```

**If `run()` returns another function** — than this is fine

```js
window.addEventListener("load", run()); // run() executes immediately  
                                        // but returns a function in its place.

function run() {
  return function() {
    // do something
  }
}
```

since now you're not passing `undefined` — but an actual `function`.