# What's wrong with putting () at the end when calling a function?

Tags: javascript, function, parentheses

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In JavaScript, does it make a difference if I call a function with parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246928/in-javascript-does-it-make-a-difference-if-i-call-a-function-with-parentheses)

This may sound very basic, but I really don't understand.

I try to take `()` off from an event handler and it cause a bug in my JavaScript webpage, what is the difference between putting and not putting `()` at the end when calling a function.

My example is:

```
document.getElementById("searchField").onkeyup = searchSuggest;
```

when I changed to `searchSuggest()`, my function was not working.

Can anyone please explain to me? If I make any part unclear, please ask, thank you.

Comment: I think the duplicate link should answer your question; say so if it doesn't.

Answer (score 6):

When you write:

```
document.getElementById("searchField").onkeyup = searchSuggest();
```

You're *calling* the `searchSuggest` function and assigning *the value it returns* to the `onkeyup` member. In your case, you probably want to assign *the function itself* to `onkeyup`, so you should write:

```
document.getElementById("searchField").onkeyup = searchSuggest;
```