# Can I add a <hr> to a javascript alert?

Tags: javascript, alert

I have the following statement:

```
alert("Testing 123\n\n Testing 231");
```

---

I wanted to add a '< hr >'-liked tag between both \n\n.
Is there any method to make a line in between?

Comment: This isn't related to java

Comment: Why not: '-------------------------------'

Comment: You can just add it: `alert("Testing 123\n<hr>\n Testing 231");` But HTML is not parsed in an alert box, if that's what you expect, so it's just the literal characters "<hr>" of course.

Comment: the alert box size is different for every browser so '------' is not a valid way to do it..

Comment: rgthree thats why i wanted to find another method to do it and i want to know how can this be done

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add `HTML` code into an alert box, unfortunately.

However, you could attempt to simulate one if you *really* want a horizontal line in there; something like this would do the trick:

`alert("Testing 123\n________________________\n Testing 231");`

I wouldn't really recommend this though because getting the `_____` across the entire alert box wouldn't be practical to do, since the width of an alert box is relative to the particular browser, so there isn't really any uniformity.

Comment: He's not asking to add html code, he's asking to have a similar effect as a <hr> tag with other means.

Comment: thank you for this and i do understand the width of an alert box is relatively linked to the browser,that's why i'm looking for another way to do it

Answer (score 0):

**No**, you cannot add html tags in the browser alert function.

BUT you can do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079674/jquery-ui-alert-dialog-as-a-replacement-for-alert) IF you are using jQuery UI.

```
$("<div>Testing 123<br/><hr/><br/>Testing 231</div>").dialog();
```