# confused over js notation when calling functions

Tags: javascript, notation

The accepted answer below explains why checkit(x) doesn't work.

I'm a little confused by the following notation:

```
const array1 = [5, 12, 8, 130, 44];

function checkit(x){
return x == 8;}

const found = array1.find(element => element > 10);
const found1 = array1.find(function(x){return (x < 10);});
const found2 = array1.find(checkit);

console.log(found,found1,found2);
```

found and found1 make perfect sense to me.  Why in found2 do we not have to name the variable being tested?  i.e. Why not:

```
  found2 = array1.find(checkit(x));
```

Could someone provide a reference?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a real question.

Comment: @r3wt I think it's as real a question as [How can I pass a parameter to a function without it running right away?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9638361/691711).  The misunderstanding is how passing functions to functions that expect function references work.  Maybe you could close as a duplicate of [In JavaScript, does it make a difference if I call a function with parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3246928/691711).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In JavaScript, does it make a difference if I call a function with parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246928/in-javascript-does-it-make-a-difference-if-i-call-a-function-with-parentheses)

Comment: you're asking a question about basic syntax, and there is no point to this question at all. `function checkit(x){return x == 8;}` is the same as `x=>x==8` or `function(x){return x==8}`. not sure why that is confusing to you. you can pass a function by reference(technically the reference is pass by value), an anomymous function or a closure as a callback. basic syntax stuff for dynamic languages like javascript,php or python. you don't have to provide typing for the callback when passing it. also, `function checkit(x){...}` is really just syntax sugar for `var checkit=function(x){...}`

Comment: I know it's a question about syntax but closures are not so basic.  That's why I asked for a reference. Which I note that no one was able to provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.find()` accepts a function.  You gave it a function: `checkit`.  Giving it `checkit(x)` would actually mean giving it what the call to `checkit(x)` is so you'd actually be saying `Array.find(false)` (or an error since `x` doesn't exist outside the scope).

```js
const array1 = [5, 12, 8, 130, 44];

function checkit(x) {
  return x == 8;
}

// A reference to a function
const foundArg = element => element > 10;

// Another reference to a function
const found1Arg = function(x) {
  return (x < 10);
}

// More function references
const found2Arg = checkit

// BAD! found3Arg is now a boolean!
//const found3Arg = checkit(x);

const found = array1.find(foundArg);
const found1 = array1.find(found1Arg);
const found2 = array1.find(found2Arg); 
//const found3 = array1.find(found3Arg); // Error!

console.log(found, found1, found2);
```

Comment: then how come the anonymous function requires we pass  x?

Comment: Check my answer. We have already done it while defining checkit.

Comment: @DCR you never explicitly pass `x`.  `Array.find()` does the passing.  You just tell it which function to pass to.

Answer (score 1):

Because the variable `checkit` refer to a function. You don't want to call this function yet, you want the callback to do it.

`array1.find(checkit(x))` will execute the function `checkit` with a parameters `x` and takes it's return values as the callback, we don't want that. We just want the `find` function to take the function reference stored in the `checkit` variable.

See example below.

```js
function functionThatTakesACallback(callback) {
  return callback();
}

let callback1 = () => {
  console.log('this is the callback1');
}

let callback2 = () => {
  console.log('this is the callback2');
}

let shouldWeTakeCallback2 = (bool) => {
  return bool ? callback2 : callback1
}

// will log 'this is the callback1'
functionThatTakesACallback(callback1)

// will execute shouldWeTakeCallback2 and takes it's returns value as the callback
// so it will log 'this is the callback2'
// if we change the boolean value to false, it would log 'this is the callback1' 
functionThatTakesACallback(shouldWeTakeCallback2(true))
```

Comment: then how come the anonymous function requires we pass  x?

Comment: Because it needs to be of the correct definition to be a valid filter callback, just like the `function(x){return (x < 10);}` filter. But we don't need to pass parameters to the callback because we do not want it to be run now. We want the callback to call it when it is ready. I've edited my answer with some example. Maybe this will help @DCR

Answer (score 1):

In `found` and `found1` you are defining an **anonymous function** and `find()` takes that as an argument whereas with `found2` `checkit` function is already defined and it directly takes in that as argument.

With anonymous functions we have to define the parameters that anonymous functions take, hence `found` and `found1` take argument and not `found2`as you have already done it when declaring it.

```
 found2 = array1.find(checkit(x));
```

Here you are actually calling `checkit` with an undefined argument `x` rather than passing the function as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

`Array.prototype.find` takes a function as the argument. When you pass the function by name, it's just shorthand for `array1.find(x => callback(x))`.