# casperJS Can't find variable : $

Tags: module, casperjs, evaluate

I'm trying to call a function defined in another module using `this.evaluate()`.

The code snippet(calling the function) is:

```js
this.waitFor(function check() {
    var re = this.evaluate(universe.answer(couponElement, url));
    if (re != 'no' & re!='yes' & re!=null) {
        couponObj.push(re);
```

and the module in which the function is defined is like this:

```js
var require = patchRequire(require);

var utils = require('utils');
exports.answer = function(couponElement, url) {
    var lblInvalidCoupon = 'lblInvalidCoupon';
    var tolTipCouponinner='tolTipCouponinner';
    var txtFCCoupondisocunt = 'txtFCCoupondisocunt';
    var btnRemoveFCCoupon = 'btnRemoveFCCoupon';

    var check = $('#txtCouponCode').css('backgroundImage');
    if (check.indexOf('ajax-loader.gif')>-1){        
        return 'no';
    } else {
        if (document.getElementById(lblInvalidCoupon)!=null){
```

Basically, I want to call the function using `this.evaluate` but unable to do so.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that the remote page has jQuery loaded? You can do this by visiting the page in your browser and trying to use a jQuery function with the browser's developer tools.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In JavaScript, does it make a difference if I call a function with parentheses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246928/in-javascript-does-it-make-a-difference-if-i-call-a-function-with-parentheses)

Answer (score 0):

First, try with the simplest `evaluate`: `remote.message` event to capture `console.log` from page.

```
casper.on("remote.message", function(msg) { 
    console.log("[page] " + msg); 
});

this.evaluate(function () { 
    console.log("Hi phantomworld! I am hello-ing from remote page!"); 
});
```

Next, check if jQuery is present:

```
this.evaluate(function () { 
    console.log(typeof jQuery); 
});
```

If it says, `[page] function`, jQuery *is* present in the page. You need to dig more...

If not, inject it:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    clientScripts:  [
        'includes/jquery.js'
    ]
});
```

Answer (score -3):

You didn't actually pass the `answer` function to `casper.evaluate`, but you called it instead. The problem is that in this way `answer` was not executed in page context and because of this `$` is not defined. `casper.evaluate` which executes a function in page context is sandboxed. It cannot use variables which are defined outside. The passed function must be self contained.

To fix this the arguments which are consumed by `answer` can be passed as additional parameters to [`casper.evaluate`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate).

Change the line

```
var re = this.evaluate(universe.answer(couponElement, url));
```

to

```
var re = this.evaluate(universe.answer, couponElement, url);
```

If JQuery is not present in the page you need to follow [sudipto's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19115594/1816580).