# My html button isn't working with my js function

Tags: javascript, html, function, button

```js
function idk() {
let cypher = {A:"G",B:"L",C:"Z",D:"E",E:"Y",F:"R",G:"D",H:"N",I:"K",J:"W",K:"J",L:"B",M:"Q",N:"F",O:"S",P:"C",Q:"V",R:"X",S:"I",T:"O",U:"M",V:"T",W:"A",X:"U",Y:"H",Z:"P"};
var answer  = prompt('What cypher are you going to use 1 - 26', 1);
var encrypt = prompt('Enter text you want encrypted', 'abc');
var output  = "";

if (answer == 1) {
    encrypt = encrypt.toUpperCase();

    encrypt = encrypt.replace(/[^A-Z]/gm, '');
    encrypt = encrypt.split('');

    encrypt = encrypt.map(letter=> {
        var letterIndex = letter.charCodeAt(0) - 65;
        return Object.values(cypher)[letterIndex];
    })
    document.write(encrypt.join(''));
    
}
function seedCypher() {
    let cypherVals = [], randomLetter;
    while(cypherVals.length < 26){
        do {
            randomLetter = String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * 26) + 65);
        } while(cypherVals.indexOf(randomLetter) !== -1);
        cypherVals.push(randomLetter);
    }
    
    let cypherOutput = {};
    cypherVals.forEach((val, i)=>cypherOutput[String.fromCharCode(i+ 65)] = val);
    return cypherOutput;
}
cypher = seedCypher();
}
```

```css
/*lol css be empty*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>replit</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <button type='button' onClick=idk>Encrypt</button>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  
</body>

</html>
```

That's my code.  I don't understand why the button isn't working with the function.  It has the closed paratheses and the () at the end of the function.  I already tried to put the function idk between '' and "", so that doesn't change the output.  When I run it, the button will appear, but when I click the button, nothing happens.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why in Javascript event handler functions with parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20485425/why-in-javascript-event-handler-functions-with-parentheses)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `()`. Also, you should use `""` and it's `onclick` not `onCLick`

```
<button type='button' onclick="idk()">Encrypt</button>
```

```js
function idk() {
let cypher = {A:"G",B:"L",C:"Z",D:"E",E:"Y",F:"R",G:"D",H:"N",I:"K",J:"W",K:"J",L:"B",M:"Q",N:"F",O:"S",P:"C",Q:"V",R:"X",S:"I",T:"O",U:"M",V:"T",W:"A",X:"U",Y:"H",Z:"P"};
var answer  = prompt('What cypher are you going to use 1 - 26', 1);
var encrypt = prompt('Enter text you want encrypted', 'abc');
var output  = "";

if (answer == 1) {
    encrypt = encrypt.toUpperCase();

    encrypt = encrypt.replace(/[^A-Z]/gm, '');
    encrypt = encrypt.split('');

    encrypt = encrypt.map(letter=> {
        var letterIndex = letter.charCodeAt(0) - 65;
        return Object.values(cypher)[letterIndex];
    })
    document.write(encrypt.join(''));
    
}
function seedCypher() {
    let cypherVals = [], randomLetter;
    while(cypherVals.length < 26){
        do {
            randomLetter = String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * 26) + 65);
        } while(cypherVals.indexOf(randomLetter) !== -1);
        cypherVals.push(randomLetter);
    }
    
    let cypherOutput = {};
    cypherVals.forEach((val, i)=>cypherOutput[String.fromCharCode(i+ 65)] = val);
    return cypherOutput;
}
cypher = seedCypher();
}
```

```css
/*lol css be empty*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>replit</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <button type='button' onclick="idk()">Encrypt</button>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  
</body>

</html>
```