# Difference of calling a function with and without parentheses in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I was handling a JavaScript file upload event. And I have the following initializer and the following function:

*Initializer*

```
    $('#s3-uploader').S3Uploader({
        allow_multiple_files: false,
        before_add: progressBar.show,
        progress_bar_target: $('.upload-progress-bar'),
        remove_completed_progress_bar: false
    }).bind("s3_upload_complete", function(e, content) {
        console.log(content);
    });
```

*Function*

```
var progressBar = {
    show: function() {
        $('.upload-progress-bar').show();
        return true;
    }
}
```

In the initializer, I noticed there is a difference if I do

`before_add: progressBar.show` v.s. `before_add: progressBar.show()`. With the parentheses, it will be called once even if it is bound to the `before_add` option, and without the parentheses it will not.

Is there an explanation for the behaviour I observed?

Comment: *With* parenthesis the method is invoked *because* of the parenthesis, the *result* of that invocation will be stored in before_add. *Without* the parenthesis you store a reference (or "pointer" if you will) to the function in the variable. **edit:** Added as [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30751972/215042) which should be more appropriate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In JavaScript, does it make a difference if I call a function with parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246928/in-javascript-does-it-make-a-difference-if-i-call-a-function-with-parentheses)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*With* parentheses the method is invoked *because* of the parentheses, and the *result* of that invocation will be stored in before_add.

*Without* the parentheses you store a reference (or "pointer" if you will) to the function in the variable. That way it will be invoked whenever someone invokes before_add().

If that didn't clear things up, maybe this will help:

```js
function Foo() {
    return 'Cool!';
}

function Bar(arg) {
    console.log(arg);
}

// Store the >>result of the invocation of the Foo function<< into X
var x = Foo();
console.log(x);

// Store >>a reference to the Bar function<< in y
var y = Bar;
// Invoke the referenced method
y('Woah!');

// Also, show what y is:
console.log(y);

// Now, try Bar **with** parentheses:
var z = Bar('Whut?');

// By now, 'Whut?' as already been output to the console; the below line will
// return undefined because the invocation of Bar() didn't return anything.
console.log(z);
```

If you then take a look at your browsers' console window you should see:

```
Cool!
Woah!
function Bar(arg)
Whut?
undefined
```

Line 1 is the result of invoking `Foo()`,
Line 2 is the result of invoking `Bar()` **"via"** `y`,
Line 3 is the "contents" of `y`,
Line 4 is the result of the `var z = Bar('Whut?');` line; the Bar function is **invoked**,
Line 5 shows that invoking `Bar()` and assigning the result to `z` didn't return anything (thus: *undefined*).

Answer (score 4):

Functions are first-class in JavaScript. This means they can be passed around, just like any other parameter or value. What you're seeing is the difference between passing a function and passing the value said function returns.

In your example:

```
before_add: progressBar.show
```

You want to pass `progressBar.show` instead of `progressBar.show()` because the former represents a function (`function () {$('.upload-progress-bar').show(); return true;}`) whereas the latter represents a returned result (`true`).

Here's another example:

```js
// All this function does is call whatever function is passed to it
var callAnotherFunction = function (func) {
    return func()
}
// Returns 3 — that's all
var return3 = function () { return 3 }

// `callAnotherFunction` is passed `return3`
// so `callAnotherFunction` will `return return3()` === `return 3`
// so `3` is printed
document.write(callAnotherFunction(return3))

// `callAnotherFunction(return3())` is the same as `callAnotherFunction(3)`.
// This will print nothing because, in `callAnotherFunction`
// `func` is 3, not a function
// so it cannot be invoked, so nothing is returned
// and `document.write` doesn't print anything.
document.write(callAnotherFunction(return3()))
```