# Javascript window object, window+'', what does this code do

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to solve a portswigger lab (https://portswigger.net/web-security/cross-site-scripting/contexts/lab-javascript-url-some-characters-blocked) and I can't understand why this code didn't pop up an alert when the expression window+'' is omitted:

```
x=x=>{onerror=alert; throw 1337},toString=x,window+''
```

A full explaination of this code snippet would be really appreciated, thanks.

Comment: there is login form....

Comment: the link is not taking me to your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the code is using the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) (see also [What does a comma do in JavaScript expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3561043)). What the comma operator does is allow you to evaluate multiple expressions. In particular in this case, you have three:

```javascript
   x=x=>{onerror=alert; throw 1337},toString=x,window+''
// ^______________________________^ ^________^ ^_______^
//                 1                     2         3
```

Let's examine them one by one:

## Brief note about implicit globals

This is going to be relevant for most of the below sections, so I want to clear it up first. Any time you assign to any name you haven't declared with `var`, `let`, or `const` it implicitly assigns to a property on the global object. In the browser, the global object is `window`, so any implicit globals go there:

```js
console.log("before assignment");
console.log("'foo' in window:", 'foo' in window);
console.log("window.foo:", window.foo);

foo = 42;

console.log("after assignment");
console.log("'foo' in window:", 'foo' in window);
console.log("window.foo:", window.foo);
```

## An arrow function

```javascript
x=x=>{onerror=alert; throw 1337}
```

### Definition

This will create a new arrow function and assign it to `x`. Since there is no variable declaration, `x` will be an implicit global and thus attached to `window`. This isn't extremely useful - it's likely done to save a few characters. The function also takes a single parameter called `x` but does nothing with it. Again, nothing useful - saves up a single character, otherwise it needs to be defined as `()=>`.

### Body part 1

What is more interesting is what that function does.

```javascript
onerror=alert
```

First of all it assigns `onerror` to `alert`. Both of these will be the [global error handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror) and the [global `alert()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) passed as a reference. So, any time *any* error happens, it just shows an alert:

```js
window.onerror = alert;

JSON.parse("{"); // parsing error
```

See [What is the difference between a function call and function reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886272/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-call-and-function-reference) and [Difference of calling a function with and without parentheses in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30751892/difference-of-calling-a-function-with-and-without-parentheses-in-javascript) for more information on how function references are used. In short, if you assign a function to a handler, then invoking that handler actually runs the function.

### Body part 2

Then what happens is that the arrow function throws an error with `throw 1337`. In JavaScript, you can assign any value to be thrown, so it doesn't really matter whether it's an error or not. Throwing a number is thus valid. The value thrown isn't really relevant since the important thing is throwing an error. Due to the first part of the function, this `throw` statement will trigger the global error handler. Here is a demonstration (formatted):

```js
x = x => {
  onerror = alert;
  throw 1337
}

x();
```

SO far, so good, but that's *not* how the function is invoked in the code. Let's go to the next part.

## Overriding `toString`

```javascript
toString=x
```

This part will *override* the `toString` method on `window` and change it tot he `x` function. Thus any time you explicitly or *implicitly* convert `window` to a string, it will instead execute `x`.

```js
x = x => {
  onerror = alert;
  throw 1337
}

toString = x;

window.toString();
```

## Converting `window` to string

In JavaScript, when you try to concatenate any value with a string, the value will be implicitly also be converted to a string. This is usually done by calling the `toString()` method:

```js
const value1 = { "foo": 42 };
const value2 = { 
  "foo": 42,
  toString() {
    return `foo is ${this.foo}`;
  }
};

const value3 = { 
  "foo": 42,
  toString() {
    return "Hello world";
  }
};

console.log(value1 + ""); //default `toString()` method of objects
console.log(value2 + "");
console.log(value3 + "");
```

The same thing happens in the last part of the code:

```javascript
window+''
```

This will:

1. trigger conversion to a string, which
2. calls the `toString` method on `window`, which
3. was overridden with `x` using `toString=x`, which
4. calls the `x` function instead, which
5. sets the global error handler to just be `alert` (`onerror=alert) and immediately throws an error (`throw 1337`), which
6. invokes the global error handler

## Why omitting `window+''` doesn't throw an error

Hopefully clear from the above, but to address it directly - that code is needed to set off the whole chain of reactions defined before it.

Here is the full code with explanation and formatting for clarity:

```js
//create a function
window.x = x => {
  onerror = alert; //changes the global error handler
  throw 1337       //throws an error to trigger the error handler
};

//overwrite the `toString` method of `window` so it always throws an error
window.toString = window.x; 

//implicitly call `window.toString()` by performing a string concatenation
window + '';
```

Comment: I love you! Thanks very much!