# GSAP timeline various onComplete functions on different tweens

Tags: javascript, animation, gsap, scrollmagic

First of all I'm new with GSAP and ScrollMagic, so forgive me if I might be asking a silly question here. I've been looking over the internet but didn't succeed in finding the right answer for my problem.

Anyways, I'm trying to create a timeline where on the complete of each 'to' function a call to an external function will be made with specific params.

```
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
var timeline = new TimelineLite();
var div = $('div');

timeline.to(div, 0.5, {
   opacity: 0,
   onComplete: toggleOverlay(0)
}, "part-1")

.to(div, 0.5, {
   opacity: 1,
   onComplete: toggleOverlay(1)
}, "part-2")

.to(div, 0.5, {
   opacity: 0,
   onComplete: toggleOverlay(2)
}, "part-3");

var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
   triggerElement: "#trigger-event",
   duration: 500
})
.setTween(timeline)
.addTo(controller);

function toggleOverlay(i){
   console.log(i);
}
```

What happens here: The timeline will be called once the scroll position reaches the '#trigger-event'. Subsequently, the '.to' functions will be called based on the scroll position after the trigger event and before the end (duration).

The problem I face here, is that the onComplete functions are called directly on the page load. This has probally something to do with the '.setTween(timeline)', as I can imagine it loads in the whole timeline.

What would be the solution for my problem or what would be an good alternative method?

EDIT: Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/04db5ja5/

Thanks in regards,
Enzio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have invoked the functions immediately by using parenthesis `()`. Have a read of **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246928/in-javascript-does-it-make-a-difference-if-i-call-a-function-with-parentheses)** answer to understand better the difference between assigning a function to a variable and actually executing it immediately.

In GSAP, the way to go about it would be to have `triggerOverlay` function assigned to `onComplete` without the parenthesis like so:

```
...
onComplete: toggleOverlay
...
```

And to receive the additional parameters you have something called `onCompleteParams` to pass them to, as an array, like so:

```
...
onCompleteParams: [0]
...
```

So your overall code should look like:

```
...
timeline.to(div, 0.5, {
   opacity: 0,
   onComplete: toggleOverlay,
   onCompleteParams: [0]
}, "part-1")

.to(div, 0.5, {
   opacity: 1,
   onComplete: toggleOverlay,
   onCompleteParams: [1]
}, "part-2")

.to(div, 0.5, {
   opacity: 0,
   onComplete: toggleOverlay,
   onCompleteParams: [2]
}, "part-3");
...
```

Comment: I didn't know about that untill now. Thank you :)

Comment: Always good to read the **[`documentation`](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TimelineMax/)** first ;)