# difference between calling a function and assigning a function reference in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and want to understand the difference between the two :

## Hello

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageOnloadHandler() {
        var a = 5;
        var b = 6;
        document.write(a + b);
   }
 `window.onload = pageOnloadHandler();`
```

Output is : 
    Hello
    11

But when I write, 
    `window.onload = pageOnloadHandler;`

Output is : 11

Comment: <h1>Hello</h1>
 
<script type="text/javascript">
 function pageOnloadHandler() {

   var a = 5;
   var b = 6;
   document.write(a + b);
  }

 window.onload = pageOnloadHandler();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In JavaScript, does it make a difference if I call a function with parentheses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246928/in-javascript-does-it-make-a-difference-if-i-call-a-function-with-parentheses)

Answer (score 0):

It's because when document.write() is executed after document is loaded it overwrites the whole document

When you type this:

```
Window.onload = pageOnloadhandler();
```

you pass the result from the function and not the function itself so window.onload would be undefined as your function doesn't have a return value

But when you use

```
Window.onload = pageOnloadhandler;
```

You give the window.onload object the function itself which is then executed onload