# Boolean value in javascript

Tags: javascript

Ok, I've got an issue I don't understand.

I have a boolean value which I test and if `true` I do something. 
BUT javascript never go in it even if the var is `true`.

I try this :

```
if(isConfigD)
    handleConfigurationD;
```

this :

```
if(isConfigD == true)
    handleConfigurationD;
```

And this :

```
if(isConfigD === true)
    handleConfigurationD;
```

But nothing work whereas `isConfigD` is always set on `true` :(

What am I missing ?

Comment: Can you show a larger example of your code?

Comment: "BUT javascript never go in" --- how do you know that? When debugging, always check the facts, not derivatives from the facts.

Comment: @zerkms with the debugger

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In JavaScript, does it make a difference if I call a function with parentheses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246928/in-javascript-does-it-make-a-difference-if-i-call-a-function-with-parentheses)

Comment: @Shadam so how could you use debugger and did not see that the function is not called?

Comment: @zerkms that was actually my question ;)

Comment: @Shadam your question was why the check does not pass: "BUT javascript never go in". Do you seriously not see the difference between what you said and "why is function not called"?

Comment: @zerkms the fact was when the debugger stop on `if(isConfigD)` it doesn't go on the line where the `handleConfigurationD;` is.

Comment: @Shadam well, that's not true https://jsfiddle.net/kp15rwzr/ Not sure why you think that lying helps, but whatever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You condition works well, but if you call a function, then you need parenthesis for the call.

```
handleConfigurationD();
//                  ^^
```

Comment: And worth noting that the first one is the correct way to check: `if (isConfigD)`

Answer (score 1):

`handleConfigurationD` is just an identifier. That statement is going to have one of two outcomes:

- A ReferenceError
- "Yup, that's a bit of data"

Presumably you have stored a function in it and want to **call** the function.

```
handleConfigurationD();
```