# Difference of wrapping a function in a closure?

Tags: javascript

[In a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41415430/1804173), I was encouraged to ask this follow up: What difference does it make to wrap a function `some.func` into something like `(arg) => some.func(arg)` if I know that `some.func` only takes one argument?

As a concrete example: In my other question I observed a surprising difference between using

```
.on("mouseover", tip.show)
```

versus

```
.on("mouseover", (d) => tip.show(d))
```

In this case the first version did have the expected behavior, while the second version was behaving differently (see [jsfiddle of other question](https://jsfiddle.net/vb3xfe5k/5/)). The reason here was that I accidentally made `tip` a global.

The more general question: Why do they behave differently in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `tip.show(d)`, that function will be called passing `tip` as the `this` value.

When you use `tip.show` as the event listener, it will be called with the current event target as the `this` value.

```js
var obj = {checkThis: function(e) {
  console.log(this === e.currentTarget, this === obj);
}};
document.body.addEventListener('click', obj.checkThis);         // true, false
document.body.addEventListener('click', e => obj.checkThis(e)); // false, true
document.body.click();
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two major differences.

We would need to see more context to determine which of these applied in this case.

## `this`

The value of `this` inside the `show` function depends on how the function is called.

If the event handler is the function itself, then `this` is the object on which the event handler is bound.

If the event handler is a function that calls `tip.show`, then `this` is `tip`.

Further reading: [How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

## Timing

In one case the value of `tip.show` is evaluated when the event handler is registered.

In the second, the value is evaluated when the event handler is triggered.