# Passing a function to .attr('d')?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am attempting to use two different area generators inside one `.data()` selection, so that one set of points can have an area rendered from top to bottom while the second set's area can be rendered from left to right. I can pass fat arrow functions to every `.attr()` except 'd', which produces the following error:

`Error: <path> attribute d: Expected moveto path command ('M' or 'm'), "function area(da…".`

I need to access the selection index in order to set the area from an array of booleans. [Please see the jsfiddle I've set up with the relevant code.](https://jsfiddle.net/L4hx6Lv5/49/) I've commented two of my attempts to pass a function to the `.attr('d')`.

Comment: Interestingly, even a simple, empty fat arrow function like `mySelection.attr('d', () => myArea)` throws an error

Comment: I'm using Opera, don't get errors and I can see graph. What's your browser??

Comment: It fails to load (after commenting line 18 and uncommenting line 19 or lines 20-26) in both Chrome and Firefox for me, although only Chrome throws an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you inspect your generated code, you'll see this:

[image]

So, you are not geting values. Instead call the function.

Add `(d)` to the return value so that the area generator function is executed:

```
  .attr('d', function(d, i){
    if (horizontalNotVertical[i]) {
        return horizontalArea(d);
    } else {
        return verticalArea(d);
    }
  })
```

Comment: This works for me, thanks! I guess it makes sense that D3 simply executes a function if passed to `attr('d')`, whether that function is a fat arrow function or an area generator, but I'm curious as to why D3 doesn't similarly execute the area generator returned by the fat arrow function.

Comment: On both cases, you need to give the data: .attr('d', (d, i) => (horizontalNotVertical[i]) ? horizontalArea(d) : verticalArea(d))

Comment: Sorry, my comment was unclear. I was wondering why D3 executes the area generator automatically if it's passed by itself (`.attr('d', myArea)`) but doesn't automatically execute if the area generator is returned by an anonymous function...but now I realize that if D3 were to execute a functions returned by functions, it could lead to a recursion error!

Answer (score 1):

The issue in your code is simply the famous **first argument** in D3.

Your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49520535/d3-js-v4-pass-function-to-attrd#comment86049227_49521191):

> I was wondering why D3 executes the area generator automatically if it's passed by itself (`.attr('d', myArea)`) but doesn't automatically execute if the area generator is returned by an anonymous function...

Is not correct. D3 has no problems executing functions returned by functions.

When you do...

```
.attr('d', myArea)
```

... the datum is automatically passed as the first argument to `myArea`. Let's see a basic demo:

```js
var data = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
var sel = d3.select("body").selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("whatever")

sel.attr("whatever", callback)

function callback(d) {
  console.log("The datum is " + d)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

So, if you want to put your `myArea` function inside an anonymous function, you have to specify the first argument, because the datum is passed to the outer function, not to `myArea`:

```
.attr('d', function(d){
//1st arg here------^
    myArea(d);
//and here-^
});
```

Let's see it:

```js
var data = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
var sel = d3.select("body").selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("whatever")

sel.attr("whatever", function(d) {
  callback(d);
})

function callback(d) {
  console.log("The datum is " + d)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Therefore, in your case, you just need:

```
.attr('d', (d, i) => (horizontalNotVertical[i]) ? horizontalArea(d) : verticalArea(d));
```

Just to show that D3 has no problems executing a function returned by another function, have a look at this last snippet:

```js
var data = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
var sel = d3.select("body").selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("whatever")

sel.attr("whatever", function() {
  callback();
})

function callback() {
  console.log("I don't have the datum!")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zt5vxbm6/

Comment: While trying to answer a [question](/questions/57204200) which is the TypeScript flavor of this question I thought there must be a nice dupe target for this type (don't want to close as duplicate, though, just reference it).  Even your answer starts of talking about the *famous* first argument, i.e. *don't call the function, just pass its reference*... However, I wasn't able to find a nice, canonical target. Are you aware of any?

Comment: @altocumulus maybe [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3246928/5768908)?

Comment: That's too general. I was looking for one specifically targeting D3.