# What does using a function name without parentheses do in an if statement in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, function-call

**For example:**

```
function foo (parameter1, parameter2) {
    // does something
}

if (foo) {
    foo(parameter1, parameter2);
}
```

Calling a function without parentheses was talked about in a different question ([In JavaScript, does it make a difference if I call a function with parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246928/in-javascript-does-it-make-a-difference-if-i-call-a-function-with-parentheses)), but I still don't understand what the above code does.

I'm asking because I'm trying to understand what `if (drag) {..}` does in this code: https://andreasrohner.at/posts/Web%20Development/JavaScript/Simple-orbital-camera-controls-for-THREE-js/

Comment: if (foo exists) call foo()

Comment: The function object, when it exists and is defined as some function, is a truthy value that will count as a positive for the if conditional. If the function didn't exist, it would throw an Uncaught ReferenceError.

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out?

Comment: https://www.google.nl/search?q=javascript+detect+existence+of+function+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: This isn't a great idea. It only tests that `foo` exists and is *truthy*. `foo` can still be anything and if it's not a function it will throw and error. Also if `foo` is not defined at all, this is a reference error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code defines a global function foo with two parameters.

After that there's an if statement to check if foo is truthy(foo is your function and therefore truthy). So it calls the function foo. **But be careful, if foo was not defined your code will throw a ReferenceError**.

A much better way to check if a function exists is:

```
if (typeof foo === "function") { 
  // safe to use the function foo
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that what OP is actually asking is what the *purpose* of this `if` statement might be. If the function wasn't defined, that `if` statement will throw the same `ReferenceError` as just trying to call it right away. So if the purpose is not to check for the existence of the function, what could it be?

Answer (score 0):

This code simply check if ~~a function~~ something named `foo` exists ~~, and therefore safe to call~~.

On the other hand, if you do if `(foo())`, the code inside that if block will only execute if foo() return something equate to `true`.

Comment: Safe to call might be an exaggeration. This only tests whether `foo` is truthy, not whether it’s a function.

Answer (score 0):

By itself, it's not clear how this code is supposed to be helpful. Maybe with more context it would be clear.

Consider these options:

**1. The function `foo` was never defined:**

If `foo` is not declared then:

```
if(foo) {}
```

is a reference error. It crashes.

**2. Foo is defined, but it isn't a function**

`foo` can be anything, so if you have `foo` that looks like this:

```
let foo = true
if(foo) {
   foo()
}
```

It's an error because you're trying to call something that's not a function.

So what exactly is this piece of code trying to test for? It won't call the function if the name `foo` is declared and equals some falsy value like `0` or `undefined`, but in other cases it will crash. It looks like it is trying to protect you from errors, but it doesn't really unless there's some other context where the name is declared but may be undefined.

A common context where `foo` would be guaranteed to be declared is inside a function where `foo` is an argument. The code would make more sense in an example like:

```
someFunction(foo){
    if(foo) {
       foo()
    }
}
```

Here you can expect `foo` to exist, but you still need to trust that the caller passed a function. This would guard against a situation where the called does not pass in an argument. (i.e. calling `someFunction()`)

Comment: The code [here](https://andreasrohner.at/posts/Web%20Development/JavaScript/Simple-orbital-camera-controls-for-THREE-js/), under Browser Mouse Events, calls the `drag(deltaX, deltaY) {...}` function when the mouse moved, and so the only argument passed in the event, so I'm not sure why the author did this

Comment: @HGent in the context of that code, it looks like simple defensive programming. `addMouseHandler` is a function that takes a `drag` parameter. Maybe that parameter is optional, so if it isn't passed to the function, it won't try to call it.