# Why do call the methods differently? sometimes with '()' and sometimes without '()'?

Tags: typescript

Scenario 1:

below method is from services.ts:

```
onChange(){
    if(this.initcount == null){
        this.likescount = null;
    } else {
      this.likescount = this.initcount;
    } 
}
```

when using it in component.ts:

```
  constructor(service: LikesService) {  
    this.getchange = service.onChange; ------------------> without '()'?
  }
```

Scenario 2:
below method is from services.ts:

```
getArray(){
            return this.courseArray;
}
```

when using it in component:

```
constructor(service: CoursesService) {
      this.courses = service.getArray();  --------------------> with '()' ???
  }
```

Comment: Actually, should be dupe of [In JavaScript, does it make a difference if I call a function with parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3246928/215552). TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript and does not differ in this respect.

Comment: If you aren't using parentheses, you aren't "calling" the method.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.getchange = service.onChange;
```

☝️ This isn't calling `onChange`. It is setting `getchange` to be the `onChange` function. Somewhere else in the code, you can then use `getchange` to indirectly execute the code in `onChange` by doing `getchange ()`.

Comment: That's not the line the OP is asking about. See the comments with the long arrows. Also, see the duplicate. Feel free to vote to close as a duplicate instead of answering too...

Comment: Copy paste error. Thanks. Fixed.