# Why doesn't promisify want the argument for the callback function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, async-await

The below script works, but I don't understand why one doesn't have to

```
const a = promisify(opA());
```

instead of the (correct)

```
const a = promisify(opA);
```

I mean `opA` is a function, so why not `opA()`?

```
'use strict'
const { promisify } = require('util')

const opA = (cb) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    cb(null, 'A')
  }, 500)
}

const opB = (cb) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    cb(null, 'B')
  }, 250)
}

const opC = (cb) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    cb(null, 'C')
  }, 125)
}

const a = promisify(opA);
const b = promisify(opB);
const c = promisify(opC);

(async function() {
  try {
    console.log(await a());
    console.log(await b());
    console.log(await c());
  } catch(err) {
    print(err);
  };
})();
```

Comment: Because `promisify` is a higher-order function. Notice that `a` also is a function. What could calling `a()` do if you had passed `opA()` to `promisify`? Did you check what the return value of `opA()` is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In JavaScript, does it make a difference if I call a function with parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246928/in-javascript-does-it-make-a-difference-if-i-call-a-function-with-parentheses)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I mean `opA` is a function, so why not `opA()`?

Because `opA` is a reference to the function itself.  The promise will use that reference to execute that function at a later time.

Alternatively, `opA()` executes the function (without any arguments) *now* and passes the *result* of that function call to the promise.  Since your `opA` function doesn't return anything, it would pass `undefined` to the promise.  The promise would then have nothing to execute later after it completes its operation(s).  The `setTimeout` would then also fail because `cb` is also `undefined`, because no arguments were passed to `opA()`.

Any time you do see a structure like that, either (1) it's a bug or (2) the function intentionally builds and returns a callback function intended for the promise.  For example, if you write a function which *returns* `opA` then you can invoke that function and pass its result to `promisify`.

---

An important clue to this behavior is here:

```
const opA = ...
```

`opA` is a variable, not unlike any other variable.  It contains a value or a reference to something.  In this case it's a reference to a function.  You could re-assign that variable, pass it as a function argument, set it as a property on an object, etc. just like any other.